# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card in a Bot - How to get data the user has entered

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a MS teams application that mostly renders adaptive cards when some commands are entered by the user. Have used Teams Toolkit to create a Chat Command Bot.

One adaptive card renders a form that has an Submit action button at the bottom. No matter what I do, I can't get the values the user has entered back to the Javascript application.

Here's the code for the Adaptive card:

```
import { AdaptiveCards } from "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools";
import { CardFactory, MessageFactory } from "botbuilder";


export class MyCommandHandler {
  triggerPatterns = "my-trigger";

  async handleCommandReceived(context, message) {
    // Message sender (full name)
    const sender = await context._activity.from.name;

    // Adaptive card with dynamic values
    const card = {
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "size": "Default",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "text": "Header"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Choice 1",
                    "value": "Choice 1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 2",
                    "value": "Choice 2"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "choose",
            "label": "Task:",
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "id": "dropdown-task",
            "isRequired": true,
            "value": "Choice 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Date",
            "label": "Date:",
            "isRequired": true,
            "id": "date"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Time",
            "label": "Time:",
            "isRequired": true,
            "id": "time",
            "value": "09:00"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Choice 11",
                    "value": "Choice 11"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 22",
                    "value": "Choice 22"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "Choose",
            "id": "dropdown-time-spent",
            "label": "Time spent:",
            "isRequired": true,
            "value": "Choice 11"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
            "isRequired": true,
            "id": "description",
            "label": "Description:",
            "isMultiline": true,
            "value": "Description goes here"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Submit",
                    "style": "positive",
                    "id": "submit-btn"
                }
            ],
            "id": "action-set"
        }
      ],
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.4"
    }

    const cardData = {
      title: "Command is added",
      body: "You have responded to the command"
    }
    const cardJson = AdaptiveCards.declare(card).render(cardData);
    return MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson));
  }
}
```

Is there another async function responsible for handling the submit event? I can't find anything relevant in the official docs.

Thanks!

Comment: We can get the value that user submit from adaptive card via Activity.Value property. if(turnContext.Activity.Value!= null)
{

    reply.Text = $"submit data: {turnContext.Activity.Value}";

}

Also please refer: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/actions?msclkid=b2ebb2bfcf6811ecaea3c52d9969cb53#handling-actions-when-users-click-action-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use the more updated Action.Execute

Comment: Please elaborate how to do that exactly, how it works, why it helps.